# How can I change memory at consecutive addresses?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, comparison, mplab

I am trying to test the RAM of a device I am working on by running through a range of address, lets say 0x0 to 0xfef.

I have tried numerous things, but nothing has worked. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
unsigned char temp;
unsigned char* addr = 0x0; // create ptr to point to address in mem

while(addr != 0xfef) // while not at end of mem
{
    temp = *addr; // save value at current addr
    *addr = 0xAA; // set value at addr to 0xAA
    if(*addr != 0xAA) // if value did not write properly, do not run software
        while(1);
    *addr = temp; // restore value at addr to original value
    ++addr; // move on to next addr
}
```

The only operation that appears to function in this code is setting the value at addr to 0xAA. The while and the if-statements both give the error, "Error [1128] compatible scalar operands required for comparison".

I have also tried creating pointers with the value of the addresses that I want, but trying to set a pointer to another pointer produces the error, "Error [1131] type mismatch in assignment".

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 2018-04-06:

Some more info:
I am using the PIC18F66K80. 
We can perform this functionality using the SFRs:

```
FSR0 = 0x00; 
while(FSR0 != 0xfef)
{
    temp = INDF0; 
    INDF0 = 0xAA; 
    if(INDF0 != 0xAA)
        while(1);
    POSTINC0 = temp;
};
```

The C code now runs, and modifies the memory, it turns out I was looking as the wrong place in memory...

However, it seems to fail at addr = 0xDAA. I'll note that the address of the pointer addr is 0xD08, and the address of temp is 0xD07.

Comment: `while(addr != 0xfef)` -- this will never evaluate to true unless `sizeof(int) = 1`. Try declaring `addr` to a pointer to `unsigned char` instead. And change `if(addr != 0xAA)` to `if(*addr != 0xAA)`

Comment: I assume you meant while (*addr != 0xAA)...

Comment: I did mean that, and I actually originally had addr as a char pointer, but had changed it while trying to get the code to work. Thanks for the spots.

Comment: Just a question, not every RAM cell is accessible, under normal circumstances. Did you check your data sheet? Are you trying to access an OK location? Also, what is your device? Maybe that info will make people help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely getting a type conflict, where the type of your constant is `int` and the type of the pointer or the dereferenced pointer is something of different size or sign-ness. Casting both to the same thing should work:

```
while(addr != (unsigned char*)0xfef) 
{
    temp = *addr; 
    *addr = 0xAA; 
    if(*addr != (unsigned char)0xAA) 
        while(1);
    *addr = temp; 
    ++addr; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
    if(*addr != (unsigned char)0xAA)
actually cause a signed to unsigned warning, possibly because integer promotion is enabled.

Comment: @SamsquanchIsReal Yes that is because the default type of the constant is a signed int. If you want to get rid of the warning too, you could probably do that by having a variable to compare against instead of a constant: `unsigned char my_val = (unsigned char)0xAA;` and then: `if(*addr != my_val)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. It turned out I was looking in the wrong memory, and that is why I wasn't seeing any changes.

Another issue I ran into after discovering the code was working was and issue that didn't exist while using special function registers. The pointer and variable were being overwritten, causing the test to fail (or enter the while loop).

I fixed this by using two pointers and two temp values, and checking for specific conditions that would break the normal function of the code:

```
unsigned char temp, temp2;
unsigned char * addr, * addr2;

addr = (unsigned char*) 0x0; // set addr to start of ram

//continue until at end of usable memory
while(addr != (unsigned char*) 0xfef)
{
  //if not testing address of 'addr' pointer, continue testing byte by byte
  if((int) addr != (int) &addr)
  {
    //if 'addr' is pointing to location in ram where 'temp' is being stored,
    //use 'temp2' to hold the old value instead, since it has a dif address
    if(&temp != addr)
      temp = *addr; //copy value out of address
    else
      temp2 = *addr; //copy value out of address

    *addr = 0xAA; //set RAM value at 'addr' to 0xAA

    //if value at 'addr' equals 0xAA then continue test
    if(*addr != 0xAA)
      //if value is not equal to 0xAA, then hang forever
      while(1);

    //if 'addr' is pointing to location in ram where 'temp' is being stored,
    //pull old value from 'temp2' since that is where it is stored
    if(&temp != addr)
      *addr = temp; //copy old value back to address
    else
      *addr = temp2; //copy old value back to address

    ++addr; //move on to the next byte in memory
  }
  //if testing the address of the 'addr' pointer, then perform same test
  //differently by setting both bytes of the pointer to 0xAA, and then
  //validating that both bytes are what they should be, before returning the
  //'addr' pointer back to its original value.
  else
  {
    addr2 = addr; //save the position of the ram test

    //set RAM value at addr to 0xAAAA to test both bytes of ptr
    addr = (char*) 0xAAAA;

    //check to ensure bytes in memory changed like they should have
    if(addr != (char*) 0xAAAA )
      //if both bytes are not equal to 0xAAAA, then hang forever
      while(1);
    addr = addr2 + 2; //return to correct position in memory to continue test
                      //move two bytes forward since two bytes were tested
  }
}
```